# Django migration sqlmigrate

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have created a migration file to alter unique key constraint of a model, previously it had 4 fields in unique key , now its has 5 , after running migrate command its worked fine.
but now i am unable to generate sql query using sqlmigrate.

Error is

"ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for rule_set(business_function_id,
business_process_id, process_state, status)"

In My DB right now constraint is :-

UNIQUE KEY `rule_set_business_function_id_bus_6bda6da3_uniq` (`business_function_id`,`business_process_id`,`process_state`,`rule_set_name`,`status`),

What did i do wrong?

Previous Migration

```
migrations.CreateModel(
        name='RuleSet',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('created_at', myghanta.fields.MysqlTimeStampField(auto_now_add=True, help_text='Date and Time of creation')),
            ('updated_at', myghanta.fields.MysqlTimeStampField(auto_now=True, help_text='Date and Time of modification')),
            ('process_state', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('rule_set_name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('rule_set_link', models.URLField(max_length=400)),
            ('status', models.IntegerField(blank=True, choices=[(0, 'Created'), (1, 'Loaded'), (3, 'Validated'), (5, 'InActive'), (None, 'Deleted'), (2, 'Published')], null=True)),
            ('last_status', models.IntegerField(choices=[(0, 'Created'), (1, 'Loaded'), (3, 'Validated'), (5, 'InActive'), (None, 'Deleted'), (2, 'Published')], default=0)),
            ('curr_index_name', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
            ('prev_index_name', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
            ('version', models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True)),
            ('published_version', models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True)),
            ('published_date', myghanta.fields.MysqlTimeStampField(blank=True, help_text='Date and Time of ruleset last published', null=True)),
            ('marked_unpublished', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('business_function', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='business.BusinessFunction')),
            ('business_process', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='business.BusinessProcess')),
            ('updated_by', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, related_name='last_updated', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name': 'Rule Set',
            'verbose_name_plural': 'Rule Sets',
            'db_table': 'rule_set',
            'unique_together': {('business_function', 'business_process', 'process_state', 'status')},
        },
    )
```

New Migration File

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('business', '0001_initial'),
    ('rules', '0002_auto_20200914_1227'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
        name='ruleset',
        unique_together={('business_function', 'business_process', 'process_state', 'rule_set_name', 'status')},
    ),
]
```

Traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/sqlmigrate.py", line 30, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/sqlmigrate.py", line 64, in handle
    sql_statements = executor.collect_sql(plan)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 225, in collect_sql
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor, collect_sql=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 530, in database_forwards
    getattr(new_model._meta, self.option_name, set()),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 363, in alter_unique_together
    self._delete_composed_index(model, fields, {'unique': True}, self.sql_delete_unique)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 84, in _delete_composed_index
    return super()._delete_composed_index(model, fields, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 397, in _delete_composed_index
    ", ".join(columns),
ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for rule_set(business_function_id, business_process_id, process_state, status)
```

Comment: Can u show us your `migrations` file. Your latest and second latest migrations from your app.

Comment: Just before this migrations, there should be another?

Comment: added in question

Comment: Can you provide complete traceback?

Comment: Would you explain this: `now i am unable to generate sql query using sqlmigrate.`

Comment: When i do python manage.py sqlmigrate <new_migration_file>, i am getting 


"ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for rule_set(business_function_id, business_process_id, process_state, status)"